# Почему уходит большое количество запросов с аякса на сервер?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, request

Отправляю на сервер Джанго запросы аяксом. Но почему-то они уходят в рекрсию (наверное), пока не переполнится стек. В чем может быть причина?

*P.S. проблема возникает только при клике по ссылкам.*

Если вешать `onclick()` внутри самого тега, тогда работает, как следует...

```js
$(document).on('click', $('a'), function(){
  $('#payment_form').click();
})
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.payment_form').change(function(){
    $('#payment_form').click();
  });
});

function submitForm(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var csrftoken = $('.payment_form').find('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()
  $form = $('.payment_form');
  var form_data = new FormData($form[0]);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '{% url "credit_detail" credit.slug %}',
    data: form_data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {
      $('.rate').html(data.rate + '%')
      $('.eair').html(data.eair + '%')
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" class="payment_form">
  <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="JE3p9bkSh5A6eDtavLH5Lb0hZC16nXa9">
  <label>Подтверждение дохода</label>
  <div class="radioBtn btn-group">
   <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active" data-toggle="income_proof" data-title="1">Требуется</a>
   <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm notActive" data-toggle="income_proof" data-title="2">Не требуется</a>
  </div>
  <input id="income_proof" name="income_proof" type="hidden" value="1">
  <label>Кредитная история</label>
  <div class="radioBtn btn-group">
   <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active" data-toggle="credit_history" data-title="1">Положительная</a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm notActive" data-toggle="credit_history" data-title="2">Дифференц.</a>
  </div>
  <input id="credit_history" name="credit_history" type="hidden" value="1">
  <input type="submit" id="payment_form" onclick="submitForm(event);" style="display:none">
</form>
```

Comment: `{% url "credit_detail" credit.slug %}`, разве так можно в статике? `JavaScript` не обрабатывается шаблонизатором, если не является частью шаблона, насколько я знаю.

Comment: этот скрипт в хтмл лежит

Comment: В чем смысл использовать ссылки без использования перехода по ним? Это бессмыслица. Сделайте вместо них обычный `button` и работайте. А то тут еще у ссылок `href` нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сигнатура метода `on` (https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) либо

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

либо

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ] )
```

У вас же вместо селектора написан jquery объект. Вот и вся проблема